# missing site collection settings

Tags: office-365

Why there is difference between **site setting** for office 365 root site collection and other site collections?

as example where is the **Web Designer Galleries** category on root Office 365 site collection?

Root site collection: 
[image]

Another site collection:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Office 365 Support -

Sign in to Office 365 with your work or school account.

- Go to the SharePoint admin center.
- Select Settings.
- Under Custom Script, check if custom script is disabled.

If you cannot see the Custom Script option or the settings are already Allow, please let us know. It may reflect a different issue. 
If the settings are Prevent, you may switch the option to Allow so as to bring the custom scripting feature back. However, we don’t recommend you do this as custom scripts and solutions may cause unexpected security risk and load to your sites.
 
If you prefer to turn scripting on, please be acknowledged of this consequences.

- If you want to enable scripting on personal sites, select Allow users to run custom script on personal sites
- If you want to enable scripting on other user-created sites, such as team sites or project sites, select Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites.
- Select OK. It takes about 24 hours for the change to take effect.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/277832.aspx

Comment: the Settings and Custom Script is there, and the "Allow users to run custom script on personal sites" and "Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites" are enabled.

Comment: @wjervis, I prefer when I answer questions, try the scenario by my self (if I can), my issue is general issue and anyone can go and create new trial office 365 and check it, then he can apply his suggested solution, so if it is works, then  answer the question. it is better than go and post any things on answer area.

Comment: It is strange,your solution working and you are right. but I wait more than 24 hours. thank you very much